# How to get get max value in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, max

I am writing a program that finds the taxes based on a person's income. So far the problem I am running into is some numbers that come out don't round up two decimal places and keep on going and I don't know how to get the max out of all the numbers.

Here is what I have to do:

Not over $750 1% of income

$750-$2500    $7.5    plus 2% of amount over $750

$2500-$5000   $82.5   plus 4% of amount over $2500

$5000-$8000   $142.50 plus 5% of amount over $5000

Over $8000  $230.00 plus%6 of amount over $8000

Write a program named IncomeTax.java.

1. generate random number of people in the range of (1-15);
2. ask the user to enter the amount of taxable income for each person, and then

displays the tax due;

3. display the max value of taxes on the screen.

Here is my code:

```
Scanner console=new Scanner(System.in);

    double tax=0;
    double income=0;
    Random rand=new Random();
    int randomNumber=rand.nextInt(14)+1;
    for(int i=1;i<=randomNumber;i++){
        System.out.println("Person: "+i);
        System.out.println("Please enter income: ");
     double n=console.nextDouble();


        if(n<750){
             n=n*.01;
             System.out.println("Tax due: $"+n);
        }else if(n<2500){
        n=0+7.5+(n*.02);
        System.out.println("Tax due: $"+n);
    }else if(n<5000){
        n=0+82.5+(n*.04);
        System.out.println("Tax due: $"+n);
    }else if(n<8000){
        n=0+142.50+(n*.05);
        System.out.println("Tax due: $"+n);
    }else if(n>8000){
        n=0+230+(n*.06);
        System.out.println("Tax due: $"+n);

    }
```

Comment: Yea but how would I do that with all these different taxes.

Comment: Do your own homework

Comment: I finished 95% of it

Comment: If u r not implementing arrays or lists you ll find it hard to accomplish such a task

Comment: Use arrays and then find the max in the array, using a loop

Comment: I heard there is a easier ways than to implement arrays

Comment: Arrays aren't complicated in any way. ArrayList may be the easiest option, but using an Array in this example may be the best option for you.

Comment: Ok so I need to implement arrays. How do I fix the problem with the decimal place not rounding to two decimal place.

Comment: You want the maximum value of the calculated "tax due"? Then store the maximal value of `n` in a `max` variable after the if/else block.

Comment: *"How do I fix the problem with the decimal place not rounding to two decimal place."* By searching on Stack Overflow. There are already several solutions for that.

Comment: You could use a DecimalFormat. Oracle's site - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: @Atif Shah. Please study the purpose of and way of asking questions in Stack Oveeflow. Give yourself some time to brush up the basics about Java and SO. Then comeback, we all are here. thanks

Comment: The simplest way to track the max value would be to create a variable for the purpose of storing the largest tax value you've recorded so far.  Then every time you calculate a new tax value, compare it to the current "max", saving the new value if it's greater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep track of the maximum value without the need of an array. The solution is to initialize the maximum at 0, then for every number, we keep only the maximum of the previous maximum and the current number. The algorithm goes like this :

```
double max = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= randomNumber; i++) {
    double n = console.nextDouble();
    //your code that calculates n
    max = Math.max(max, n); //keeps track of the maximum value
    //... the rest of your code
}
```

[`Math.max(a, b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-double-double-) returns the maximum of the two given value.

Comment: I tried this but got error

Comment: What error did you get? What was the code?

Comment: I guess the error was the redefinition of variable `max`. You created one outside of the loop and one inside.

Answer (score 1):

Using Stream (*for the fun of it*):

```
DoubleStream.Builder builder = DoubleStream.builder();
for(int i=1;i<=randomNumber;i++){
    // ...
    builder.add(n);
    // ...
}
double max = builder.build().max().getAsDouble();
```